# boostrap combobox validation - is it possible?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, validation, combobox

Has anyone implemented jquery bootsrap validator with a bootstrap combobox? I've been trying to update my pre-existing jquery validator script, but unfortunately unsuccessful.

Is is possible?

Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//oss.maxcdn.com/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.3/js/bootstrapValidator.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" />
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js">   </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.combobox').combobox();
$('#addprofile').bootstrapValidator({
   container: 'tooltip',
 feedbackIcons: {
   valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
   invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
   validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
},
fields: {
   species: {
      validators: {
          notEmpty: {
              message: 'Field species cannot be empty.'
          }
   }
});
});
</script>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="species">choose a specie (english only)</label>
<select class="combobox form-control" id="species" name="species"><option value="" selected="selected">type a specie</option><option value="1">Name</option>
</select>
</div>
```