# How do I get jquery validation errors to display on a bootstrap-combobox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I've been using this very cool bootstrap-combobox from here: https://github.com/danielfarrell/bootstrap-combobox

I currently have a .NET MVC 5 project which is using its out of the box validation (jquery unobstrusive validation), and any validation errors do not show up with the combobox control. My question is similar to the one here (unfortunately it has no answers): [boostrap combobox validation - is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27956949/boostrap-combobox-validation-is-it-possible)

I took some time to create a jsfiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/1doe359f/3/

HTML:

```
<form id="experiment" action="/" method="post">
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="PersonID">Person</label>
    <select class="form-control combobox" data-val="true" data-val-required="This field is required." id="PersonID" name="PersonID">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="5">Bruce Banner</option>
        <option value="9">Bugs Bunny</option>
        <option value="8">Daffy Duck</option>
        <option value="10">Elmer Fudd</option>
        <option value="6">Jean Grey</option>
        <option value="4">Clark Kent</option>
        <option value="3">Peter Parker</option>
        <option value="7">Scott Summers</option>
    </select> <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="PersonID" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>
<p>
    <button type="submit" value="Save" role="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-disabled="false">Save</button>
</p>
```

Javascript:

```
var validator = {};
  $(document).ready(function () {
  $('.combobox').combobox();
  var $form = $("#experiment");
  // prevent form submission
  $form.submit(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
  });
  validator = $form.validate();
});
```

If you remove "combobox" from the control's class and hit the save button, you can see the error message pop up, as it should. It does not show up when the control is a combobox, however.

How can I get the validator errors to display while using this combobox control?

Usually I can stumble through this kind of thing, but this has a few too many moving parts for a javascript novice like myself. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did get this working eventually, but it's not a pretty solution. I made this change in the bootstrap-combobox code:

```
/* COMBOBOX PLUGIN DEFINITION
* =========================== */
$.fn.combobox = function ( option ) {
    return this.each(function () {
    var $this = $(this)
      , data = $this.data('combobox')
      , options = typeof option == 'object' && option;

    if (!data) { $this.data('combobox', (data = new Combobox(this, options))); }
    if (typeof option == 'string') { data[option](); }

    /* Added stuff to get jquery validation working */
    data.$element.attr("name", data.$source.attr("id"));
    data.$element.attr("data-val", data.$source.attr("data-val"));
    data.$element.attr("data-val-required", data.$source.attr("data-val-required"));
    data.$element.closest("form").removeData("validator").removeData("unobstrusiveValidation");
    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(data.$element.closest("form"));
  });
};
```

The gyst here is that I copy the relevant attributes (name, data-val, data-val-required) from the original dropdown ($source) to the combobox control ($element), and then I reset the validator so that it recognizes this newly-made control.

FYI: This is not a great approach because it creates a dependency to jquery validator in the bootstrap-combobox, and it is inflexible (will only do a 'required' check). One reason I took this shortcut was that the control that is generated doesn't have any good identifiers, so it was much easier to use this banked reference.

It does work though, and if you're only doing 'required' checks on your combobox and only using jquery validation in your project, it is adequate. Hopefully it at least gives some insight to save someone time in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I have used errorPlacement within that validate function to handle controls that are particularly whiny.

```
errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                // Set positioning based on the elements position in the form
                var elem = $(element);
                // Check we have a valid error message
                if (!error.is(':empty')) {
                    if (elem.is(':combobox')){...logic here}
```

There have also been controls that I have used that have a container around them, that causes the error to be hidden instead of showing up on the container.

Comment: Thank you for the response; I'm still unsure of what logic I'm supposed to use. Were you able to get it working in the jsfiddle?